# What is the significance of a black and white Union Jack?

Tags: united-kingdom, flag, symbols

Recently, I was in [Levanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levanto,_Liguria) on the Italian coast between Genoa and La Spezia, when I noticed, flying above an apartment building, a [Union Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack) in which the red and blue sections had been replaced with black. Otherwise, it was exactly the same as the British flag.

[image: Black and white Union Jack flag]

I asked a local person if they knew anything about why such a flag should be flying. They didn't, but speculated that it may have been put there by a supporter of the Juventus football team, whose colours are black and white.  But as for why it was in the form of the Union Jack remains a mystery.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Technically, it's not the Union Jack either - unless it's been hung [upside down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom). Distress signal, maybe?

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere You are correct that it is flying upside down.

Answer (score 6):

While I can't be certain what the intention of the person flying the flag might be, supporters of Newcastle United Football Club sometimes wave black and white Union Jacks. Some are [on sale at ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NUFC-Black-White-5x3-Flag-Union-Jack-Sports-Newcastle-United-Football-Toon-Army-/170971764435)

Other suggestions are: An ironic reflection of the phrase "There aint no black in the union Jack" (indicating someone who is black, british and proud). Or it may just be a fashion symbol

Some have suggested that the flag may have been proposed by British Fascists or British Anarchists - I can find no evidence of this.

Comment: I thought the expression "There ain't no black in the Union Jack" belonged to right-wing racists.

Comment: @WS2 hence 'ironic reflection'

Answer (score -2):

I thought it was to do with honouring fallen British soldiers or police and others in the line of duty protecting the unarmed

Comment: Welcome to PoliticsSE. Do you have a reference for that use of the flag?